# What is the use of photo_image and where is the name come from?

Tags: python, tkinter

This is the program about display camera videocapture in tkinter component. I was wondering where is 'photo_image' method or instance came from because I think there is not attribute in tk.label is called 'photo_image'. I already know it is use for displaying image in tk.label but still I don't know how does it work. I thought if I only configure image in the label and it will be work. Can someone tell me the detail about it? Thank you so much.

```
import UI as ui
import tkinter as tk
import cv2
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

class face_recognition_class(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        self.master = master
        self.video_w = 600
        self.video_h = 400
        self.cap_obj = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
        self.cap_obj.set(3, self.video_w)  # width of video
        self.cap_obj.set(4, self.video_h)  # height of video
        self.cap_obj.set(10, 150)  # brightness
        # self.video_obj = tk.Canvas(
        #     self.master,
        #     width=self.cap_obj.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH),
        #     height=self.cap_obj.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT),
        # )
        self.video_obj_label = tk.Label(self.master)
        self.video_obj_label.grid(column=0,row=0,padx=200)
        self.face_recognition()

    def face_recognition(self):
        ret, frame = self.cap_obj.read()

        frame = cv2.flip(frame,1)  # flip video image to follow correct direction of movement
        photo = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
        photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.fromarray(photo))

        self.video_obj_label.photo_image = photo
        self.video_obj_label.configure(image=photo)

        #self.video_obj.create_image(0, 0, image=photo, anchor='nw')

        if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            return None
        else:
            self.video_obj_label.after(1, self.face_recognition)
```

Comment: There is a line in your code that sets the attributes, which will create it if it does not exist yet

Comment: If you removed that assignment to the `photo_image` attribute, you'd find that your window ended up with a blank rectangle of the right size, but no actual image.  Merely displaying an image via a Label or other widget unfortunately does not keep the image from being garbage-collected; the use of the image is happening entirely outside of the Python environment, so Python can't detect that it is actually being used.  Storing a reference to the image in some attribute of the widget is the standard solution, the exact name of that attribute is the programmer's choice.

Answer (score 1):

The `photo_image` attribute is not a built-in attribute of the `tk.Label` widget. It is a custom attribute created by the programmer to store the reference to the `PhotoImage` object.

The `photo_image` attribute is used to store the reference to the `PhotoImage` object so that it remains accessible and doesn't get garbage-collected, allowing the video frames to be displayed correctly on the `Label` widget.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have used a local variable `photo` to store the instance of `ImageTk.PhotoImage()`, so it will be garbage collected after exiting the function `face_recognition()`.  In order to avoid the garbage collection, most of the suggestions is to use a *custom attribute* (any name that is not the same as any of the built-in attributes) of the label, and so the image will not be garbage collected as long as the label exists.

For your case, you can use an instance variable `self.photo` instead of an attribute of the label instead.

Comment: I understood the concept right now but why would garbage collection happen if I still using photo variable in configure function?

Comment: `.configure(...)` just pass the parameters to the underlying TCL interpreter and the current Python interpreter does not interface with it directly, so it does not know that `photo` is used by it.  So when the function exits, all local variables created inside the function will be garbage collected and the reference count of the instance of image will be zero and garbage collected as well.